# Do hiding panel load controls in it

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have an asp.net page having three sections:
Post
Courier 
HandDelivery

I pass values from a page to this asp.net page using querystring and depending upon the value the other two panels are hidden during Page Load.

I have a dropdown list with SQL databound and other controls in each panel.

I want to know if these controls are loaded even if hidden or what is the best way of doing it?

Comment: open developer console in your browser, and see if the hidden element's html is being rendered. if you want the elements not to be rendered, you need to create them in the code behind and add them to the page on `page_load`

Comment: It is not showing in the developer console even though I have not added it on Page Load. Is this the right way of doing it?

Comment: Without seeing your code, i don't know if your way is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you should use - combination of

**[Ajax Tabs](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/Tabs/Tabs.aspx)**

and

**[iFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)**

```
<ajax:TabContainer ID="tabID" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1" CssClass="ajax__tab_blueGrad-theme"
            AutoPostBack="true" >
            <ajax:TabPanel ID="tab1" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <span style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; font-weight: bold;">Post
                    </span>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <iframe id="iframe1" src="Post.aspx" runat="server" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="500px"
                        width="100%"></iframe> // Post.aspx - your first page
                </ContentTemplate>
            </ajax:TabPanel>
            <ajax:TabPanel ID="tab2" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <span style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; font-weight: bold;">Courier </span>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <iframe id="iframe2" src="Courier.aspx" runat="server" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="500px"
                        width="100%"></iframe> // Courier.aspx your 2nd page
                </ContentTemplate>
            </ajax:TabPanel>
            <ajax:TabPanel ID="tab3" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate >
                    <span style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; font-weight: bold;">HandDelivery</span>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <iframe id="iframe3" src="HandDelivery.aspx" runat="server" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="500px"
                        width="100%"></iframe> // HandDelivery.aspx your 3rd page
                </ContentTemplate>
            </ajax:TabPanel>
        </ajax:TabContainer>
```

You can use `Ajax Tabs` as your 3 `panels` and inside each `panels` call your `.aspx` pages.